# How do I use a button to start audiotrack and stop audiotrack?

Tags: android

So I have a button that will play audiotrack when pressed and then stop audiotrack when pressed a second time.  When I click the button it quits the application.  I have no idea why.  Please help!

```
public void Playbutton(View view) {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

            int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

            int bufferSizeInBytes = (int) (file.length() / shortSizeInBytes);
            short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

                int i = 0;
                while (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                    audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                    i++;
                }

                dataInputStream.close();

                AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        11025,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                        bufferSizeInBytes,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                if (playbuttonstatus){
                playBtn.setText(getString(R.string.stop));
                audioTrack.play();
                audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);
                    playbuttonstatus = false;}
                else{
                    playBtn.setText(getString(R.string.play));
                    playbuttonstatus = true;
                    audioTrack.pause();
                    audioTrack.flush();}
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Post the error that you are getting when the application quits.

Comment: Maybe try to catch any exception first.. to see what kind of error you get

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your project. I think it will help you:

```
    Boolean audiopaused=true;

    Button play.setOnclickListener(new Onclicklistener){
    if (audiopaused){
        audio.start();
        }esle{
        audio.stop();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you always run the same initializations regardless of the state of `playbuttonstatus`. So after you have first started the playback on one instance of `AudioTrack` and press the button again you then create another new instance of `AudioTrack` and try to stop it although it's not playing yet. That probably causes an `IllegalStateException`. (And also you fail to stop the original one.)

You could have `audioTrack` as a member variable of the class outside the `playButton()` method:

```
private AudioTrack audioTrack;
```

And then you could change your code so that the same `AudioTrack` is started and stopped.

```
public void playButton(View view) {

    if (playbuttonstatus){
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int) (file.length() / shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSizeInBytes,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            playBtn.setText(getString(R.string.stop));
            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);
                playbuttonstatus = false;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        playBtn.setText(getString(R.string.play));
        playbuttonstatus = true;
        audioTrack.pause();
        audioTrack.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I also found out that for some reason the AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO had to be changed to AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO.  When I set it to CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO it says that it is deprecated. Do you have any idea what I should do?  Is this a big deal?  I believe it causes lag in terms of the button response.

Comment: `CHANNEL_IN_MONO` is for recording and `CHANNEL_OUT_MONO` is for playback, so just use `CHANNEL_OUT_MONO` instead of the deprecated `CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO`.